# HTTP call with angular-meteor

Tags: angular, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm trying to get `HTTP.call` work with `angular-meteor`.

From my API (backend) folder, I'm trying this in a method:

```
this.unblock();
try {
  const result = HTTP.call('GET', 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self?oauth_token=RHFPPND0TSNNC0FUADM2FO3CVTRX3T1KS1IKC2245YRENYYS&v=20170928');
  return result;
} catch (e) {
  return false;
}
```

And it always returns `false`.

It seems that the `HTTP.call` always fails, and I assume this is to do with not having `import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http';` which causes my code to crash with:

> Can't find npm module 'meteor/http'."

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Meteor HTTP documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html):

> `HTTP` provides an HTTP request API on the client and server. To use these functions, add the HTTP package to your project by running in your terminal:
>
> ```
> meteor add http
> ```

Comment: thanks, I overlooked this in the doc :) it works just fine now